# How to find cdf and pdf of exponential random variable?

Tags: probability

Let Z ~ Exponential(lambda) and let W = e^Z.
1)Find the CDF of W
2)Use the CDF of W to find the PDF of W

For question 1, I got that P(W <= w) = P(e^Z <= w) = P(Z <= ln(w)) = 1 - e^(-lambda(ln(w))) but Im not too sure if this is in the right direction and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You can do math typesetting with mathjax. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good start. That is the definition of the CDF of W: $\mathbb{P}(W \leq w)$, where here, $w$ would have to be strictly greater than 0. What you have written so far works given the increasing nature of the exponential function with respect to the inequality.

Note that the exponential term you have in the last expression can be further simplified if you take the $-\lambda$ as a power inside the logarithm, and then cancel the exponential with $\ln$, being inverse functions. This will make developing the PDF (i.e. the derivative of the CDF with respect to $w$) a bit easier.

Do not forget to mention the range of your random variable, as this is also an important part of its distribution.